# What is the most easy way to get ddl sql-script from HSQLDB?

Tags: sql, export, database, hsqldb

In other words, how to export sql-script for building database and putting data into it from HSQLDB?

Answer (score 1):

Use

SCRIPT 'yourFilePathAndName'

It will save the database SQL script, including data, to the file you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse's Data Source Explorer. You can generate DDL for whole base or specify certain table.
See picture
[image: Data Source Explorer Generate DDL]

I bet other IDE's also have similar feature.